# Software for cataloging software?

Tags: windows, catalog

As it stand searching on Google for recursive  keyword like that is hard, so I ask here.
I understand this can be done in excel, but I believe something like this is typical and has been done by IT people in large corporation where they have a lot software (custom made or not).

Especially for cataloging command-line software, as this executable has no gui and often no help file accompanied. Once you have 1000+ of them in one directory (within your %PATH% lookup) after a while you started to forget "which command to do this?" "what is the correct syntax?"

So I want to know software that address above issue, with fields like "software name" "exe name" "version" "description" "syntax (for command-line)" and so on.

Clarification:
yes, most fields can be queried from PE image, as for other field I don't mind filling it manually as it may be contextual case.
The closest google could give me is app called SoftCAT free, but I'm not satisfied.

Comment: The last point (syntax) is not possible to do automatically. See also https://superuser.com/a/736452/105621

Comment: [It seems you didn't get noticed for the comment under the existing answer] If I understand OP correctly, he is not looking for the storage part. IMHO OP wants to automate the task of entering all that data manually. @posh, maybe you can clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good job for any personal wiki or outliner application.

[TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/) is a single file browser based local wiki where you can among other things create pages and tag them. Pages can have arbitrary custom fields and be searched, filtered and organized.

You can create custom fields for your "exe name" "software name" and any other data and search for it later. It is not very suited (even though possible) for multiuser environments, but works well for single users.

If you you prefer desktop software [Treeline](https://treeline.bellz.org/) outliner allows defining custom data types with named fields you can populate with any data you need stored in an hierarchical XML file based tree structure.

Comment: If I understand OP correctly, he is not looking for the storage part. IMHO OP wants to automate the task of entering all that data manually. @posh, maybe you can clarify.

Comment: Ah I see,makes sense. If that is the case then my answer is indeed invalid